# When does the native load event happen relative to the angular5 lifecycle hook?

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular5

This is angular 5 [life cycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#!#hook-sequence)

I would like to know when does the `DOM Event` [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) happen relative to the lifecycle hook

For example consider this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pzNDHVSbXpyNOWPNwKZq?p=preview)

it uses native `load` event from https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts

```
<chart [options]="options" 
       (load)="saveGraphInstance($event.context)"></chart>
```

When does the load happen?

Comment: `(load)` is an Output EventEmitter that the chart Component uses. It has nothing to do with the DOM Event: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

Comment: @ExplosionPills I see, so where is that event relayed? I can't quite find the code the connect the `highchart` event to the `load` `output` event

Comment: What do you mean where is it relayed? What is the actual issue you are running into?

Comment: how is `(load)` hooked up with `highchart event` I only see `@Output() load = new EventEmitter<ChartEvent>();` defined and not used in the [repository](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts/blob/master/src/ChartComponent.ts)

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. I couldn't quite figure it out either. I think it is done here: https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts/blob/master/src/createBaseOpts.ts#L74 -- the actual calling to the `load` event is done somewhere in the Highcharts library itself: https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts/blob/master/src/initChart.ts#L24